# php script login to td ameritrade

Tags: php, web-scraping, curl

I need to log into the TD Ameritrade website with my account. Note, I am not talking about the official API, I'm talking about their actual UI. I need to scrape from the site itself, unfortunately. I'm using curl in PHP, but any language you can get to work is probably fine. I've started with postman, which I'm usually able to get to work for this kind of thing, but it isn't returning anything when I copy the transactions from Chrome Dev Tools and importing into Postman. For example, it either loops back to the login site, or if I play with the settings it will flat out not return anything. The current issue with my php is that I get `Maximum (10) redirects followed`, it's an infinite loop where the login forwards back to itself. Unfortunately, for obvious reasons, I cannot post my username and password, so you would need an account to test. They are free, but not the easiest to set up. In any case, if you have any ideas that would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/javascript');

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://auth.tdameritrade.com/oauth?client_id=MOBI%40AMER.OAUTHAP&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Finvest.ameritrade.com%2Fgrid%2Fp%2Fsite&code_challenge=xNghkUhiiE_DSuVXLcSF1ufBVSPTQRa1ITybIyw2USc&code_challenge_method=S256',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => 1, // needed for getting cookies
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.7.3) Gecko/20041001 Firefox/0.10.1",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => 'su_username=' . $username . '&su_password=' . $password,
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => true,
    // CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    //     'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    // ),
));


//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);

// $cookie = dirname(__FILE__) . "/cookie.txt";
// curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
// curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);



$res = (object)array(
    'response' => curl_exec($curl),
    'info' => (object)curl_getinfo($curl),
    'errors' => curl_error($curl)
);
print_r($res);
```

Comment: If you check on the request using your browser dev tools, when you login via the web UI, you'll see that it sends _a lot_ more POST parameters than you are providing, including a CSRF token ...

Comment: Yeh, in my postman (and my original php) I added all of those. It didnt seem to make a difference. I will try some more (been fighting with it for 2 days so far)

Comment: The CSRF token likely needs an active session. So you will need to make a request to _fetch_ the login form first, so that you get a session cookie and can extract the corresponding CSRF token from it. And then you need to send the session ID cookie together with your second request.

Comment: Im wondering if 2FA is the issue here. Playing around with headless browsers like zombie.js and selenium atm.

Comment: Even trying that, the main auth form has a url param of code_challenge. They have so much going on its hard to mimic it. I did do as you recommended, and grab the initial page and parse csrf, but no luck past that.